# Python logger not following formatting

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use the Python logger and formatting it, but it isn't working. I have a main script that does not initialize any loggers, but imports a script which contains the following function

```
def fn(vars):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logging.basicConfig(level=loglevel,
                        format='%(asctime)s (%(relativeCreated)d ms) -> %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%I:%M:%S %p')

    logger.info('Running')
```

I get the following output on the command line after I run `fn()` : `INFO:MainThread:root:Running`

Comment: I suspect `loglevel` is something other than `INFO`, so your `logger.info()` call is not using that configuration.

Comment: Try instanciate the Logger after the `basicConfig`, if not work try passing a name to `getLogger` to not get the Root one

Comment: I've set both `loglevel` to be explicitly `INFO`, and putting the instantiation aftaer `basicConfig` and passing in `__name__` to `getLogger`, with the same outcome

Comment: Did you do what I proposed ? Create `logger = logging.getLogger()` AFTER the basicConfig ?

Comment: Is any logging or logger configuration happening earlier then the cal to fn? `basicConfig` does nothing if a logger is already configured. Be aware that any log automatically does that.

Comment: I've tried to create the logger after and it still doesn't work. No other config is done before.